# When is someone the controller of a permanent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My dad and I have an issue since we play with cards with Ascend. We both play with auras with Enchant Creature. When is an aura under who’s control? I think when he plays an aura on a creature I control, the aura is also under my control. I tried to find the rulings, but I can't find it.

Comment: Is the city's blessing related to your question?

Comment: Yes because when i got ten cards under my controle i get citys blessing, when one creature of me got an aura does it count as an permanent for citys blessing. As example, i got 5 lands, 4 creatures and a aura my opponent put on my creature.

Comment: OK, I understand. I am going to make some edits to your question to try to make it easier for future readers to understand.

Answer (score 7):

In most cases, the player who controls a permanent is the player who played it. In the situation you describe, if an opponent plays an aura with "Enchant Creature" attached to a creature you control, then your opponent still controls the aura.

Comment: So when i play a card destroy target.... opponent control i can destroy that card?

Comment: Yes, if you have an effect that only destroys things that your opponents control, and the aura is one of the things that it can destroy, then yes, you can destroy it even if it is attached to one of your creatures.

Comment: Can u explain rule 303.4e for me? I cant paste it tomy comment

Comment: The short answer is that that rule basically says what I already said in the answer. What specifically are you still confused about?

Comment: I thought in the ruling it said it is in no ones control

Comment: That's not what it says. It's just saying that who controls the aura is separate from who controls the thing it's attached to.

Comment: @Hans, A permanent is *always* under someone's control